# Redirect 302 on Laravel POST request

Tags: php, api, laravel

I'm developing a `Laravel Web Service`. 
When I try my `POST` routes with web forms, everything works fine, but when I try the same with a REST Client like `Postman` it doesn't get me the response that should.

It gives me status code `302`, and redirects to "/". What's the problem?

Comment: did you use token for csrf from postman?

Comment: nope, is this necessary? in middleware i've already removed csfr token middleware.

Comment: try run this command php artisan routes

Comment: if you mean route:list, I've tried it and in the middleware column I've got anything

Answer (score -2, accepted):

it looks like in postman you should point that the data you send is 'x-www-url-formurlencoded'

Comment: you need to be send  'x-www-url-formurlencoded' this in post method for ios app.What backend engine you use for ios app.You can use php for backend.If you use php for backend you can send this through CURL or guzzle a php dependency.

Comment: My backend is made with Laravel, and my POST route is a simple register route which returns a token. In my website made with laravel works correctly.

Comment: SOLVED: the problem was that my request had some required fields that I missed in my request.

Comment: I want to cry. I just spent the last hour tearing whats left of my hair trying to figure this out. BLOODY FORM REQUEST

Comment: @Bellots I wish you'd create an answer to your own question with the actual solution. This answer is accepted, but it's clearly incomplete and I have to read your comments to find out what you actually did.

Answer (score 10):

This might be useful for other users that having the same problem cannot solve it with the accepted solution.

Make sure that the form fields names for instance `<input type="text" name="document_name">` **(document_name)**, match the names of the rules fields declared in the model. 
`public static $rules = ['document_name' => 'required|string'];`

It doesn't throw any errors, nothing in the logs, it just redirects to the form, therefore the difficulty to find the problem.

Comment: THANK YOU this was exactly my problem I was using a different name on the input and in the rules.

Comment: Here...thanks...this was my problem too..thanks

Comment: That was my problem. I had an "id" attribute on input form, but not a "name" attribute.

Answer (score 4):

When you try to POST request by Postman,you need to add _token field and it's value which is used to be protect XSS attack.See https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#csrf-protection

Comment: Instead of posting links as answer add some text to explanation how this answer help to OP in fixing current issue.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When visiting the endpoint using Postman, set the Header

`Accept: application/json`

or Laravel would never know it's an API client and thus redirect with 302 message.
It's the mechanism for latest Laravel version since they provide api.php router beside web.php router.

Answer (score 0):

Http status code 302 is used for redirection. It can be due to server side problem, Please check your **laravel project's error log file** or **apache's error log file.**