# POST request in laravel 5 with token via PhpUnit?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpunit, forms

I am trying to test my Laravel APIs using phpunit and I am using the `$this->call();` method to perform calls and see if they are working fine.

I am also JWT for authentication and hence have to pass my token with it. Simple GET requests are easy:

```
$response = $this->call('GET', 'users?token=' . $this->token);
```

But when I need to create a new user or any resource for that matter, I am trying to do:

```
$response = $this->call('POST', 'users/?token=' . $this->token, $user);
```

But it is giving me a redirect like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>\n
<html>\n
    <head>\n
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />\n
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://localhost" />\n
\n
        <title>Redirecting to http://localhost</title>\n
    </head>\n
    <body>\n
        Redirecting to <a href="http://localhost">http://localhost</a>.\n
    </body>\n
</html>
```

Now when I did some digging, I came across this:

[Redirect 302 on Laravel POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30297607/redirect-302-on-laravel-post-request)

And the API for the call method looks like so:

```
$response = $this->call($method, $uri, $parameters, $cookies, $files, $server, $content);
```

So I tried this:

```
$response = $this->call('POST', 'users/?token=' . $this->token, $user, [], [], [], ['Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded']);
```

But I am still getting a redirect. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't try something like this?

```
$token = ‘your token’;
$method = ‘POST’;
$params = [];
$response = $this->call($method,'http://api.api.app/api/',
    $params,[],[],['HTTP_Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token],[]);

$this->response = $response;
$this->seeStatusCode(200);
```

Update:

You have CORS enabled in Laravel? Maybe this is the reason.

Use the header: `'HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH' => 'XMLHttpRequest'`

Or try [laravel-cors](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors) package.

Comment: I was trying `Authorization` instead of `HTTP_Authorization`. Anyway, I now tried that too and still the same. `$response = $this->call('POST', 'users/?token=' . $this->token, $user, [], [], [], ['HTTP_Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $this->token]);`

Comment: Try with the complete URI, just in case.

Comment: Same. Moreover, I tried it with a test route and dumped `request()->header()` to see all the headers present. Cannot see the `HTTP_Authorization` header present there, although `"content-type":["application\/x-www-form-urlencoded"]` is present.

Comment: My bad, I was passing it in the last array instead of the second last. But I am still there with the redirect. The only thing that changed was that the request has the header present now.

Comment: You're using dingo in strict mode? Maybe you need two more headers:

`Accept : application/x.visitapeldoorn.v1+json`
`Content-Type : application/json`

Comment: `$response = $this->call('POST', 'users?token=' . $this->token, $user, [], [], ['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH' => 'XMLHttpRequest'], []);` This works. Can you explain why?

Comment: You have CORS enabled in [Laravel](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors)?  Maybe this is the reason, for my test i don't need use this header.

Comment: Yes, CORS is enabled. I guess you are right. That must be it. Update your answer and I will accept it. Thank you for helping me out.